# How to change body background colors gradually like windows 8 using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to change body background colors continuously like Windows in JQuery.
e.g color change from blue to pink smoothly.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963059/jquery-animate-div-background-color-gradient

Comment: use css3 transition refer https://jsfiddle.net/RRR0308/btf7u0r5/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Gradient fill using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/481468/gradient-fill-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963059/jquery-animate-div-background-color-gradient)

```
   -webkit-transition: background 5s ;
    -moz-transition: background 5s ;
    -ms-transition: background 5s ;
    -o-transition: background 5s ;
    transition: background 5s ;

.background_animation_element{

    -webkit-transition: background 5s ;
    -moz-transition: background 5s ;
    -ms-transition: background 5s ;
    -o-transition: background 5s ;
    transition: background 5s ;

    background: rgb(71,234,46);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(71,234,46,1) 0%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(71,234,46,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,63,63,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(71,234,46,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(71,234,46,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(71,234,46,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(71,234,46,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#47ea2e', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 );

}

.background_animation_element.yellow{

    background: rgb(247,247,49);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%, rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(247,247,49,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(63,63,63,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(247,247,49,1) 0%,rgba(63,63,63,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#f7f731', endColorstr='#3f3f3f',GradientType=0 );

}
```